# JPA merge() is removing duplicate row instead of throwing constraint violation

Tags: java, junit, jpa-2.0

I currently have 2 classes : AgencyDetail and AgencyBlockedDayDetail defines as follows:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "startDate","endDate","agency_detail"}))
public class AgencyBlockedDayDetail extends CalendarEvent {

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "agency_detail", nullable=false)
private AgencyDetail agencyDetail;
```

**Note that variables startDate and endDate are declared in superclass CalendarEvent.**

And the AgencyDetail class is:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"}))
@RooJpaActiveRecord(finders = { "findAgencyDetailsByNameEquals"})
public class AgencyDetail extends LocationDetail {

@NotNull
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "agencyDetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<AgencyBlockedDayDetail> blockedDays;
```

The problem is when I have two AgencyBlockedDayDetail objects i.e. 
bdd1 with a reference to an AgencyDetail object agency01 and 
bdd2 with a reference to an AgencyDetail object agency02.

I have the scenario where I update the AgencyDetail on bdd2 as follows: 
    bdd2.setAgencyDetail(agency01); 
    agencyBlockedDayDetailService.updateAgencyBlockedDayDetail(bdd2);

At this point bdd1 and bdd2 are logically equivalent according to my equals() and hashCode() methods. However after the merge() runs in the update method of the service layer, bdd2 is removed/deleted completely. I would prefer a constraint violation exception to be thrown since attempting to save this would violate the unique constraint I have specified (i.e. startDate, endDate, agencyDetail).

Is this the correct behaviour? Can I get it to throw the constraint violation exception rather than just merging? This would be preferable as the user may have accidently entered in the wrong dates or agency detail.

An example of my jUnit test that fails is as follows:

```
public void test() {
    //now attempt to update agency
    AgencyDetail agency = agencyDetailService.findAgencyDetail(3l);//Get agency Rolling Hills
    AgencyBlockedDayDetail agencyBdd= AgencyBlockedDayDetail.findAgencyBlockedDayDetailsByAgencyDetail(agency).getSingleResult();
    assertTrue(agencyBdd.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase("Blocked Day for Rolling Hills"));
    AgencyDetail agency02 = agencyDetailService.findAgencyDetail(2l);//Get agency Fairlane Agencies
    agencyBdd.setAgencyDetail(agency02);
    agencyBlockedDayDetailService.updateAgencyBlockedDayDetail(agencyBdd);
    agency02 = agencyDetailService.findAgencyDetail(2l);//Get agency Fairlane Agencies
}
```

Comment: Where are you primary keys ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The PK is the ID field which is automatically inserted into the database.

Comment: What does the update method in your service layer ? And does you persistance layer have an option to show the SQL commands sent to database (Hibernate does, don't know for others) ?